# web technology supported on IE but not in Chrome

Tags: href

Not allowed to load local resource: file://inbom1-fil001/dept_data/MumbaiWebpage/ETS without changing any compability setting in browser is it possible to run ?

Comment: I can't quite understand your question. Can you please give more details?

Comment: I was trying to open that above link in google chrome that time error was occur like Not allowed to load local resource but it's works on IE11 so i don't  understand why it's not supported in chrome?